# Excel or pentaho formula to get sum of distinct values in a column

Tags: excel, formula, pentaho

I want to add a formula in penthao report to get sum of distinct values in a column. The formula of penatho is similar to excel. So how do i do that in excel. Please help.

Comment: In Excel probably would be a `SUMIF` https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b

Comment: or, depending on your version of excel, SUMIFS()

Comment: There are some suggestions here https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1705-excel-sum-average-unique-values.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this can be done in a single cell, but it certainly is possible by adding in an extra column.  For instance, if your range is A1:A25, you can type this formula in Cell B1 and drag it down to cell B25:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(OFFSET($A$1,0,0,ROW(),1),$A1)=1,1,0)
```

This formula enters a 1 if the value in the range is the first occurrence, and 0 otherwise.  The last step is to use a simple sumproduct for the final result:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($A$1:$A$25,$B$1:$B$25)
```

[image]

Comment: It is called `Sumif`using following syntax: `Sumif(A1:A24;1)`, You are making a sumproduct, instead of just a sum.